# How to set a child item of a QTreeWidget tobe auto selected and highlighted when click on its parent

Tags: python, pyside2

Here is my code ,it will work for sometime but most times don't. I have searched for this but the solutions just don't work.

(I am using pyside2, not pyqt5)

Click parent

[image]

AutoSelect child

[image]

```
import sys
import time

from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget,QPushButton,QApplication,QListWidget,QGridLayout,\
QLabel,QMainWindow,QLineEdit,QScrollArea,QVBoxLayout,QMessageBox,QComboBox,QMenu,QAction,\
QDialog,QTreeWidget,QTreeWidgetItem,QSlider,QAbstractItemView,QHBoxLayout
from PySide2.QtCore import QTimer,QDateTime,QSize,Qt,Signal,Slot,QThread,QMutex,QMutexLocker,QItemSelectionModel
from PySide2.QtGui import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.resize(320, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("--")
        self.setStyleSheet(
            """
            QMainWindow
            {
                background-color:white;
                color:white;
                margin:0px
            }
            """
        )
        self.InitializeWindow()

    def InitializeWindow(self):
        self.center = QWidget(self)
        self.center.setGeometry(0, 0, 320, 300); 
        layout=QHBoxLayout()

        self.tree=QTreeWidget()
        self.tree.setColumnCount(1)
        self.tree.setHeaderLabels(['func'])

        root1=QTreeWidgetItem(self.tree)
        root1.setText(0,'-A')

        self.tree.setColumnWidth(0,100)
        self.child1_1=QTreeWidgetItem(root1)
        self.child1_1.setText(0,'--aa')

        self.child1_2=QTreeWidgetItem(root1)
        self.child1_2.setText(0,'--bb')

        root2=QTreeWidgetItem(self.tree)
        root2.setText(0,'-B')

        self.child2_1=QTreeWidgetItem(root2)
        self.child2_1.setText(0,'--cc')

        self.child2_2=QTreeWidgetItem(root2)
        self.child2_2.setText(0,'--dd')

        self.child2_3=QTreeWidgetItem(root2)
        self.child2_3.setText(0,'--ee')

        self.tree.addTopLevelItem(root1)
        self.tree.addTopLevelItem(root2)

        self.area_op=QWidget()
        self.area_op.setMinimumWidth(100)
        self.area_op.setStyleSheet(
            '''QWidget
            {
                background-color:white;
                color:white;
                font-size:15px;
                border:0px solid #708090;
                margin:0px
            }'''
            )

        self.tree.currentItemChanged.connect(self.tree_onClick)

        layout.addWidget(self.tree)
        layout.addWidget(self.area_op)
        self.center.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()

    def tree_onClick(self):
        getSelected = self.tree.currentItem()
        #print(str(sys._getframe().f_lineno),getSelected)
        if getSelected:
            if(getSelected.text(0)=='--cc'):
                pass
            elif(getSelected.text(0)=="-A"):
                getSelected.setExpanded(True)
                self.tree.setCurrentItem(self.child1_1)
            elif(getSelected.text(0)=="-B"):
                getSelected.setExpanded(True)
                self.tree.setCurrentItem(self.child2_1,0,QItemSelectionModel.Select)
                if self.child2_1.isSelected()==False:
                    self.child2_1.setSelected(True)
            else:
                pass
        else:
            print(str(sys._getframe().f_lineno),"tree error ",getSelected)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: If the system tells you that your post is mostly code and asks you to add more context, don't just put random noise in there. Instead clarify your question and add context. Please [edit] it and explain what you mean by "works sometimes". Under which conditions? What happens when / what do you mean by "doesn't work"? Any errors? See also [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to automatically select the first child, you shouldn't check for the item text, but if it actually has child items.

Also, using `currentItemChanged` might not be a good idea, as that signal might create some inconstinstency if you're trying to change the current item as its result (which might be the source of your problem, even if I wasn't able to reproduce it).

The solution is to use the [`itemClicked()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#itemClicked) signal instead, and also take advantage of its first argument (the clicked item).

```
        # ...
        self.tree.itemClicked.connect(self.tree_onClick)
        # ...

    def tree_onClick(self, item, column):
        if item.childCount():
            self.tree.setCurrentItem(item.child(0))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I connected the wrong signal for my purpose,  _itemClicked_ works!